# Add some commands to a method of parent class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Assume I have file A.kt with contents below:

```
open class EchoWebSocketListener(instance: MainActivity?) : WebSocketListener() {
        open fun ReceiveString(message: String?) {
            println("foo")
        }
        override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket?, text: String?) {
            output("Receiving : " + text!!)
            ReceiveString(text)
        }
}
```

And I have file B.kt with contents below:

```
class NewMessage(instance: MainActivity?) : WebSocket.EchoWebSocketListener(instance) {
    override fun ReceiveString(message: String?) {
        println(message)
    }
}
```

What I want is not to override ReceiveString(), I need to change it so after receive a message it prints "foo" and message. Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I am trying to make it simpler. Assume I have A.kt file contains:

```
class foo() {
  fun a() {
    println("foo")
  }

  //Assume this function is unchangeable and is running in a loop
  fun b() {
    fun a()
  }
}
```

Now I need a() print "foo" and "bar". But I have to add println("bar") to it dynamically from inside file B.tk. What is the solution?

Comment: Overriding *is* changing it. The fact that you want to call `super.foo` doesn't change the fact that you're overriding it

Answer (score -1):

This is how you should write your function:

```
class NewMessage(instance: MainActivity?) : WebSocket.EchoWebSocketListener(instance) {
    override fun ReceiveString(message: String?) {
        super.ReceiveString()
        print(message)
    }
}
```

you can also find an example in [Kotlin doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/inheritance.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already read that doc, but overriding such function will need to init it inside onMessage() function, that it seems impossible. The problem is, overriding a function will not change the parent method in parent class. It just create new extended method.

Comment: "*but overriding such function will need to init it inside onMessage() function*" - what do you mean by that? You don't *init functions inside other functions*.

Comment: I mean I have to put the new extended method inside onMessage() again. It seems impossible

Comment: OK, Probably I have to choose the dirty option! Looper.prepare() ...

Comment: You don't.  That's what overriding is about.  Suppose something calls `onMessage()` on a `NewMessage` instance.  `NewMessage` doesn't override `onMessage()`, so it falls back to the implementation in the superclass `EchoWebSocketListener`.  When that implementation calls `onMessage()` it will call the overridden version defined in `NewMessage`.  (In C++ terms, all method calls in Java/Kotlin are _virtual_.)  From the other perspective, any time you call a method in your class, it could actually be calling an overridden version in a subclass.

Comment: (The only way you can avoid calling an overriding version is by using the `super.` to directly call the superclass version.  As in this answer.)

Comment: "any time you call a method in your class, it could actually be calling an overridden version in a subclass" I am testing what you are saying, IT DOES NOT WORK. Just attention, we are not calling extended method inside  onMessage(), we are calling parent method. Override does not change the parent method, it extend it to a new method.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, if you want a child class to have `ReceiveString()` do something different that its parent, **then you must override the method**. It seems like this is the biggest problem with your understanding.

A common problem people encounter when first overriding is that they try to start using that function/member in the parent construction (`init`) thinking it will already be overridden by some child class. **Construction happens in order, so overriding will also happen in order**. The parent gets created, **then** the  child overrides what it needs to. If you want child functionality, the earliest time to use it  is during child initialization.

Now to answer your question as simply as I can:

> I need to change it so after receive a message it prints "foo" and
> message. Any help will be appreciated.

Solution:

```
class NewMessage(instance: MainActivity?) : WebSocket.EchoWebSocketListener(instance) {
    override fun ReceiveString(message: String?) {
        println("foo")
        println(message)
    }
}
```

If you want it to be "do what parent does, then print message":

```
class NewMessage(instance: MainActivity?) : WebSocket.EchoWebSocketListener(instance) {
    override fun ReceiveString(message: String?) {
        super.ReceiveString()
        println(message)
    }
}
```

Like Sgh mentioned. I am almost certain that overriding is what you want. If not, please **edit your question's code to be a minimal, complete example.** If the solution is giving you errors, then we won't know why unless you show us why it's breaking.